# Elastic Search query not giving correct result

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack

I have a elastic search query the query is

```
GET /My_Index_Name/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "geo_distance": {
            "addresses.location.longitudeLatitude": {
              "lat": "57.7092",
              "lon": "11.9816"
            },
            "distance": "2000km"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

this is the mapping of the field
even "longitudeLatitude" : {
"type" : "geo_point"
}

By correct result i mean, i have data of candidates, and the latitude and longitude of the candidates are stored, hence when i run this query i want those candidates records to be displayed

Comment: what is your definition of correct result? what do you expect and what do you get? what is the mapping of your index?

Answer (score 0):

##### Get Data by Distance with co-ordinates:

Here is the updated Query

```
GET /My_Index_Name/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match_all": {}   //Added a match_all clause to retrieve all documents in the index
        },
        {
          "geo_distance": {
            "distance": "2000km",
            "addresses.location.longitudeLatitude": {
              "lat": 57.7092,
              "lon": 11.9816
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "sort": [
    {
      "_geo_distance": {   //Added a sort parameter to sort results by distance
        "addresses.location.longitudeLatitude": {
          "lat": 57.7092,
          "lon": 11.9816
        },
        "order": "asc",
        "unit": "km",
        "distance_type": "plane"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: still not working

Comment: If you can share the sample data and expected output I can share the query. I have my local ES running to execute the same and get the required solution.